# html5 form validation - use pattern on optional field

Tags: regex, html, forms, pattern-matching

I have an optional form field that I want to use the new html5 pattern option.
But, when I add the pattern, the field becomes required even though I do not have the required attribute.  I have included the pattern below.  I want the user to be able to leave the field blank, but if the user enters something in the field, then I want the pattern applied.  How would I accomplish this?  Thanks in advance.

```
pattern="[-a-zA-Z '.,]{3,50}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `{3,50}` limiting quantifier requires at least 3 occurrences of the chars defined in the character class.

You need to make the pattern optional. Wrap it with an optional non-capturing group:

```
pattern="(?:[-a-zA-Z '.,]{3,50})?"
         ^^^                   ^^
```

[HTML5 patterns](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-pattern-attribute) are wrapped with the anchors automatically, i.e. the pattern above will be translated into `^(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z '.,]{3,50})?)$` and will match

- `^(?:` - start of the string
- `(?:[-a-zA-Z '.,]{3,50})?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of 3 to 50 hyphens, ASCII letters, spaces, `'`, `.` or `,`
- `)$` - end of string.

Comment: Amazing.  Thanks.  You are HTML5 genius.  I simplified it by removing the ?: at the front.  And I didn't see the end of string in your pattern above.  The simplified version worked.  Is there a reason I need a start of string and end of string?

Comment: @XiVix: See [the docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-pattern-attribute). The pattern you use in `pattern` attribute *must* match the entire string, and thus the `^` and `$` in leading/trailing positions are not necessary. That is why I did not include them into the pattern.